# SignalR 2.0 - 404 in IIS Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, signalr

I'm having an issue when deploying a very basic MVC5 app running SignalR 2.0.2.  Everything works great in my local development environment when I'm running it with IIS Express.  When I deploy to IIS, my js receives a 404 error attempting to connect to SignalR.

More specifically, I'm deploying to an application/virtual directory that is running under my Default Web Site.  When I publish directly to Default Web Site, everything works successfully so IIS is not the issue.

GET http://**myServer/signalr**/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%5D&clientProtocol=1.3&_=1395517687175 404 (Not Found)

I'm assuming the 404 is caused by the missing application name.  ie: myServer/**MyApp**/signalr/negotiate...

I've searched a number of posts and SignalR documentation with no luck regarding IIS and Applications/Virtual Directories and SignalR.  Below is snippets of code in my app.

Thanks!

JS:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var proxy = connection.createHubProxy('TestHub');

connection.start()
.done(function () {
console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id + ' using transport=' +   connection.transport.name);
                })
                .fail(function () { console.log('Could not connect'); });
```

Startup.cs:

```
 app.MapSignalR();
```

**Update**
By changing the following JS code I was able to 'fix' the issue.  The question is, how proper is this?

```
//var connection = $.hubConnection();
var connection = $.hubConnection("/MyApp/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your fix seems reasonable.

`{ useDefaultPath: false }` simply tells SignalR not to append "/signalr" to the url, so you could also create your connection object like this: `var connection = $.hubConnection("/MyApp");`

Alternatively, if you want to use JS hub proxies generated at /MyApp/signalr/hubs, you can could connect like this:

```
var proxy = $.connection.testHub;

// Make sure you always wire up client methods before calling start
proxy.client.myClientMethod = function () { /* ... */ };

$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function () { /* ... */ })
    .fail(function () { /* ... */ });
```

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy

Comment: Yep, that actually worked 'out of the box' for me when deploying to an IIS application under a Default Web Site.  I suppose I was just curious why the 'non-generated proxy' JS code fails in this scenario and why you need to apply my fix?

Comment: When you use a generated JS hub proxy, SignalR gets a chance to see what URL you used to request the generated JS (probably "/MyApp/signalr/hubs"). SignalR simply strips the "/hubs" portion at the end, and calls $.connection.hub = `$.hubConnection("/MyApp/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });` If you wanted to change this url, you could simply set `$.connection.hub.url` before calling `$.connection.hub.start()`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution which will work in dev, and in IIS hosted as application, virtual directory or root is to configure the hub using the page url as its base. This will mean you won't need to hard code the value and negates configuration change for development and deployed scenarios.

```
var connection = $.hubConnection(document.location.origin + document.location.pathname);
```